# Как исправить эту ошибку? TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Button

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, type-error

Я в процессе написания desktop-приложения на Python. Вот код:

```
import os
import smtplib
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import filedialog

# Добавляем необходимые подклассы - MIME-типы
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart  # Многокомпонентный объект
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText  # Текст/HTML
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage  # Изображения
from email import encoders



windows = tkinter.Tk()
windows.title("Automatic Send E-mail with pdf file")  # program title
windows.geometry('500x400')  # size of program
windows.sourceFile = 'D:\\CURRENT_WORK\\BKunde_Reports\\BizimKunde18.05.2021-26.05.2021.pdf'

lbl_useremail = Label(windows, text="Enter Your E-Mail address : ")
lbl_useremail.grid(column=0, row=1)


def enter_login():  # Enter login by mail here
    l = password.get()  # get login from entry
    print(l)


mail_login = StringVar()  # Login variable
loginEntry = Entry(windows, textvariable=mail_login)
loginEntry.grid(column=0, row=2)

lbl_userpassword = Label(windows, text="Enter Your password : ")
lbl_userpassword.grid(column=0, row=3)


def enter_password():  # Enter password by mail here
    p = password.get()  # get password from entry
    print(p)


mail_password = StringVar()  # Password variable
passEntry = Entry(windows, textvariable=mail_password, show='*')
passEntry.grid(column=0, row=4)

lbl_recmail = Label(windows, text="Enter Recipient E-Mail : ")
lbl_recmail.grid(column=0, row=7)


def enter_recipient_login():  # Enter login by mail here
    r_l = password.get()  # get login from entry
    print(r_l)


recipient_login = StringVar()  # Login variable
loginEntry = Entry(windows, textvariable=recipient_login)
loginEntry.grid(column=0, row=8)

lbl_subject = Label(windows, text="Subject : ")
lbl_subject.grid(column=0, row=9)


def enter_subject():  # Enter Subject of mail
    subject = password.get()  # get subject from entry
    print(subject)


subject_theme = StringVar()  # Body of mail
loginEntry = Entry(windows, textvariable=subject_theme)
loginEntry.grid(column=0, row=10)

lbl_bodyofmail = Label(windows, text="Body of mail : ")
lbl_bodyofmail.grid(column=0, row=11)


def enter_body():  # Enter Subject of mail
    body = password.get()  # get subject from entry
    print(body)


body_text = StringVar()  # Login variable
loginEntry = Entry(windows, textvariable=body_text)
loginEntry.grid(column=0, row=12)


def chooseFile():
    windows.sourceFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=windows, initialdir="/", title='Please select a file')


b_chooseFile = tkinter.Button(windows, text="Choose File", width=20, height=3, command=chooseFile)
b_chooseFile.place(x=80, y=120)
# b_chooseFile.grid(padx=170, pady=170)
b_chooseFile.grid(column=0, row=15)

pathfile = b_chooseFile

msg = MIMEMultipart()


def send_message():
    
    address_info = lbl_recmail.get()

    email_body_info = lbl_bodyofmail.get()

    sender_email = lbl_useremail

    sender_password = lbl_userpassword

    mail_send = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)

    server.starttls()

    server.login(sender_email,sender_password)

    server.sendmail(sender_email,address_info,email_body_info)


def send_attachment(pathfile):
    filename = pathfile
    attachment = open(pathfile, "rb")
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(p)
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
    msg.attach(p)

    msg['From'] = mail_login  # Адресат
    msg['To'] = recipient_login  # Получатель
    msg['Subject'] = subject_theme  # Тема сообщения

    body = body_text  # Добавляем в сообщение текст
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body.get(), 'plain'))
    # print(body)

    html = """\
    <html lang="en">
        <tbody>

        <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:transparent;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat;background-size:auto;border:0px rgb( 0 , 0 , 0 );color:rgb( 0 , 0 , 0 );font:400 16px 'times new roman';margin:0px;padding:0px;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;white-space:normal;word-spacing:0px"><tbody><tr><td><div><img data-cke-saved-src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mail-signature/474754/2679e3a0bde47475e48c450b3c6c51c5/orig" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mail-signature/474754/2679e3a0bde47475e48c450b3c6c51c5/orig" style="height:211px;width:195px"></div></td><td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td colspan="2"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:15.6933px"><tbody><tr><td style="padding:0cm"><div style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:normal;margin:0cm"><strong><span style="font-family:'arial' , sans-serif;font-size:18pt">Rahman Samedzade</span></strong></div></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0cm"><div style="line-height:15.5467px;margin:0cm"><font color="#7f7f7f" face="arial, sans-serif"><span style="font-size:12px">IT Specialist</span></font></div><div style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:15.5467px;margin:0cm"><br></div></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0cm"><br></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0cm"><div style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:22px;margin:0cm"><strong><span style="color:rgb( 13 , 13 , 13 );font-family:'arial' , sans-serif;font-size:9pt">ADDRESS: 55 Zarifa Aliyeva str., Yeni Hayat Plaza, 7th floor, Baku, Azerbaijan</span></strong></div><div style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:22px;margin:0cm"><span style="color:rgb( 127 , 127 , 127 );font-family:'arial' , sans-serif;font-size:9pt">MOBILE:&nbsp;+994 50 285 44 06</span></div><div style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:22px;margin:0cm"><span style="color:rgb( 127 , 127 , 127 );font-family:'arial' , sans-serif;font-size:9pt">WEB:&nbsp;<span style="text-decoration:none"><span style="color:rgb( 127 , 127 , 127 )"><a data-cke-saved-href="https://www.166.az/" href="https://www.166.az/" target="_blank" style="color:rgb( 153 , 0 , 153 )" rel="noopener noreferrer">www.166.az</a></span></span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<span style="text-decoration:none"><span style="color:rgb( 127 , 127 , 127 )"><a data-cke-saved-href="https://www.evakuasiya.az/" href="https://www.evakuasiya.az/" target="_blank" style="color:rgb( 153 , 0 , 153 )" rel="noopener noreferrer">www.evakuasiya.az</a></span></span></span></div><div style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:22px;margin:0cm"><span style="color:rgb( 127 , 127 , 127 );font-family:'arial' , sans-serif;font-size:9pt">EMAIL: <a data-cke-saved-href="mailto:rehman.s@166.az" href="mailto:rehman.s@166.az" rel="noopener noreferrer">rehman.s@166.az</a></span></div><div style="font-family:'calibri' , sans-serif;font-size:11pt;line-height:22px;margin:0cm"><br></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
    </html>
    """
    msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8'))  # Добавляем в сообщение HTML-фрагмент

    mail_send = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)  # Создаем объект SMTP
    # mail_send.starttls()                                  # Начинаем шифрованный обмен по TLS
    mail_send.login(str(mail_login), str(p))  # Получаем доступ
    mail_send.send_message(msg)  # Отправляем сообщение
    mail_send.quit()


b_sendattachment = Button(windows, text="Send attachment", width=20, height=3, command=send_attachment(pathfile))
b_sendattachment.place(x=100, y=115)
# b_sendattachement.grid(padx=100, pady=100)
b_sendattachment.grid(column=0, row=18)

send_attachment(pathfile)

# windows.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # Центрирует поля ввода
# windows.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # Центрирует поля ввода

addr_from = mail_login  # Destination
addr_to = recipient_login  # Recipient
password = mail_password  # Password

# ~

windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: В смысле кнопку использую как имя файла?Имя файла у меня "ver2send.py".

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку я мог отправлять выбранный файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина ошибки в следующем: вы создаете кнопку, записываете эту кнопку в переменную, в которой видимо предполагается путь к файлу, передаете в функцию `send_attachment`, внутри которой пытаетесь открыть кнопку как файл (в этот момент программа падает с ошибкой, которую можно перевести как "[путем к файлу] может быть строка, набор байт или `PathLike` объект, но не кнопка").

И все это происходит до нажатия на кнопку - весь код вне функций до вызова `windows.mainloop()` выполняется сразу при старте программы (фактически только после вызова `windows.mainloop()` появляется окно и запускается цикл обработки событий).

Ниже условный код, в том порядке, в котором что выполняется:

```
b_chooseFile = tkinter.Button(windows, text="Choose File", width=20, height=3, command=chooseFile)

...

pathfile = b_chooseFile  # Кнопка стала путем к файлу? Шта?

...

send_attachment(pathfile)  # Все та же кнопка используется как параметр функции

...

def send_attachment(pathfile):  # тут приняли кнопку
    filename = pathfile
    attachment = open(pathfile, "rb")  # Пытатесь открыть кнопку как файл
    ...
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)  # Пытаетесь указать кнопку как имя файла в заголовке сообщения
    ...
```

Вам нужно, чтобы отправка происходила только в момент нажатия на кнопку, т.е. перенести вызов функции отправки в обработчик нажатия на кнопку. А там использовать значение полученное из диалога как путь к файлу:

```
def chooseFile():
    pathfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=windows, initialdir="/", title='Please select a file')
    send_attachment(pathfile)

b_chooseFile = tkinter.Button(windows, text="Choose File", width=20, height=3, command=chooseFile)

# Строки pathfile = b_chooseFile и send_attachment(pathfile) вне функций ниже в коде нужно убрать
```

Чтобы одной кнопкой выбрать файл, потом другой кнопкой отправить, нужно при нажатии на первую кнопку вызвать диалог выбора файла, выбранный файл сохранить в глобальную переменную (или поле объекта, если используется ООП), дальше при нажатии на другую кнопку вызвать обработчик, который проверит, было ли что-то выбрано, потом вызовет отправку. Примерный код:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

pathfile = None


def chooseFile():
    global pathfile
    pathfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=windows, initialdir="/", title='Please select a file')


def sendFile():
    if not pathfile:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Сначала выберите файл")
    else:
        send_attachment(pathfile)


tkinter.Button(windows, text="Choose File", width=20, height=3, command=chooseFile)
tkinter.Button(windows, text="Send File", command=sendFile)
```

Comment: Благодарю за то что подробно объяснили.Просто дело в том,что я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку я мог выбирать местоположение файла на жёстком диске и далее отправлять по сообщению mail.

Comment: Выбрать и сразу отправить? или выбрать, потом нажать другую кнопку и отправить? Как выбрать и сразу отправить показано в последнем куске кода в ответе.

Comment: Выбрать файл,далее после того как все поля кнопок будут заполнены нажав на кнопку сообщение отправилось.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: Кнопка "Send_file" почему-то не отображается

Comment: Нужно place или grid вызывать для кнопки.

Comment: Я выбираю файл,всё правильно на этот раз,но почему-то выдаёт ошибку,хотя всё правильно.

Comment: Какую именно ошибку?

Comment: Доменная почта Яндекса,раньше такой ошибки не было,почему-то сейчас появилась. 

**smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password!')**

Comment: Ну, судя по ошибке неправильную почту или пароль передаете. Нужно проверить правильно ли вводите и правильно ли передается на сервер.

Comment: Все данные верны.Я тоже самое делал только без GUI.Всё прекрасно работало.

Comment: Если без GUI работало, значит проблема определенно в коде. Вы можете задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: понятно,спасибо